# Error using integral: A and B must be floating-point scalars

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to evaluate the simple example of integral

```
a = max(solve(x^3 - 2*x^2 + x ==0 , x)); 
fun = @(x) exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
q = integral(fun,0,a)
```

and the error is

```
Error using integral (line 85)
A and B must be floating-point scalars.
```

Any tips? The lower limit of my integral must be a function, not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Matlab command `solve` returns symbolic result. `integral` accepts only numeric input. Use `double` to convert symbolic to numeric. As your code is written now, already `max` should throw an error due to symbolic input. The following works.

```
syms x;
a = max(double(solve(x^3 - 2*x^2 + x)));
fun = @(x) exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;
q = integral(fun,0,a)
```

Output: `1.9331`.

> the lower limit of my integral must be a function, not a number

`integral` is a numeric integration routine; the limits of integration must be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Check values of a by mouse over in breakpoint or removing the ; from the end of the line so it prints **a**.   Based on the error, **a** is not a scalar float.   You might need another max() or double() statement to transform the vector to a single value.

Solve Help : http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Integral Help : http://www.mathworks.com/help/ref/integral.html

Comment: Using == in solve is correct syntax. `=` would throw an error, illegal assignment.

Comment: You are looking at MuPad help page. [Here's Matlab function help page for solve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html).

Comment: LOL.   My bad.   You can leave off the == 0 part entirely, as it is assumed.